# Jboss error New missing/unsatisfied dependencies jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources

Tags: oracle, web-applications, jboss, datasource

I have the following datasource, we are using oracle jdbc driver, ojdbc6.jar :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<datasources xmlns="http://www.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema">
  <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/hubAdminDS" enabled="true" 
   use-java-context="true" pool-name="hubAdmin" jta="false">
    <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.0.153.177:1521:XE</connection-url>
    <driver>ojdbc6.jar</driver>
    <pool>
      <min-pool-size>5</min-pool-size>
      <max-pool-size>10</max-pool-size>
      <prefill>true</prefill>
    </pool>
    <security>
      <user-name>HUBDBLOCAL</user-name>
      <password>HUBDBLOCAL</password>
    </security>
  </datasource>


  <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/TASK_DB" enabled="true" 
   use-java-context="true" pool-name="TASK_DB" spy="true" use-ccm="true">
    <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.0.153.177:1521:XE</connection-url>
    <driver>ojdbc6.jar</driver>
    <pool>
      <min-pool-size>10</min-pool-size>
      <max-pool-size>20</max-pool-size>
      <prefill>true</prefill>
    </pool>
    <security>
      <user-name>HUBDBLOCAL</user-name>
      <password>HUBDBLOCAL</password>
    </security>
  </datasource>

 <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/SAFE" enabled="true"  
  use-java-context="true" pool-name="SAFE" jta="false">
   <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.0.153.177:1521:XE</connection-url>
   <driver>ojdbc6.jar</driver>
   <pool>
     <min-pool-size>3</min-pool-size>
     <max-pool-size>4</max-pool-size>
     <prefill>true</prefill>
   </pool>
   <security>
     <user-name>HUBDBLOCAL</user-name>
     <password>HUBDBLOCAL</password>
   </security>
 </datasource>

 <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/JDBC_DB" enabled="true" 
  use-java-context="false" pool-name="JDBC_DB" jta="false">
   <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.0.153.177:1521:XE</connection-url>
   <driver>ojdbc6.jar</driver>
   <pool>
      <min-pool-size>5</min-pool-size>
      <max-pool-size>10</max-pool-size>
      <prefill>true</prefill>
    </pool>
    <security>
      <user-name>HUBDBLOCAL</user-name>
      <password>HUBDBLOCAL</password>
    </security>
  </datasource>

  <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/MAIL_SENDER_DB" 
   enabled="true" use-java-context="true" pool-name="MAIL_SENDER_DB"
   jta="false">
    <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.0.153.177:1521:XE</connection-url>
    <driver>ojdbc6.jar</driver>
    <pool>
      <min-pool-size>3</min-pool-size>
      <max-pool-size>4</max-pool-size>
      <prefill>true</prefill>
    </pool>
    <security>
      <user-name>HUBDBLOCAL</user-name>
      <password>HUBDBLOCAL</password>
    </security>
  </datasource>

   <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/HELPDESK" enabled="true" 
    use-java-context="true" pool-name="HELPDESK" jta="false">
     <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.0.153.177:1521:XE</connection-url>
     <driver>ojdbc6.jar</driver>
     <pool>
       <min-pool-size>10</min-pool-size>
       <max-pool-size>20</max-pool-size>
       <prefill>true</prefill>
     </pool>
     <security>
       <user-name>HUBDBLOCAL</user-name>
       <password>HUBDBLOCAL</password>
     </security>
   </datasource>
</datasources>
```

when I deploy the application, I got the following error :

```
15:44:40,915 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) 
JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
  service jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.JDBC_DB (missing) dependents: [service jboss.naming.context.java.module.bpm.bpm.env."com.hds.hub.api.processes.impl.UserServicesEJB".dataSource, service jboss.naming.context.java.module.bpm.bpm.env."com.hds.hub.iArchive.impl.FileArchiveServiceEJB".dataSource] 
  service jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.MAIL_SENDER_DB (missing) dependents: [service jboss.naming.context.java.module.bpm.bpm.env.jdbc.MAIL_SENDER_DB] 
  service jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.TASK_DB (missing) dependents: [service jboss.naming.context.java.module.bpm.bpm.env.jdbc.TASK_DB, service jboss.persistenceunit."bpm.war#org.jbpm.persistence.jpa"] 
  service jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.hubAdminDS (missing) dependents: [service jboss.naming.context.java.module.bpm.bpm.env.jdbc.HUB_ADMIN_DB] 

15:44:40,921 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) {"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.naming.context.java.module.bpm.bpm.env.\"com.hds.hub.iArchive.impl.FileArchiveServiceEJB\".dataSourcejboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.JDBC_DBMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.module.bpm.bpm.env.\"com.hds.hub.iArchive.impl.FileArchiveServiceEJB\".dataSourcejboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.JDBC_DB]","jboss.naming.context.java.module.bpm.bpm.env.jdbc.HUB_ADMIN_DBjboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.hubAdminDSMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.module.bpm.bpm.env.jdbc.HUB_ADMIN_DBjboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.hubAdminDS]","jboss.naming.context.java.module.bpm.bpm.env.jdbc.TASK_DBjboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.TASK_DBMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.module.bpm.bpm.env.jdbc.TASK_DBjboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.TASK_DB]","jboss.naming.context.java.module.bpm.bpm.env.\"com.hds.hub.api.processes.impl.UserServicesEJB\".dataSourcejboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.JDBC_DBMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.module.bpm.bpm.env.\"com.hds.hub.api.processes.impl.UserServicesEJB\".dataSourcejboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.JDBC_DB]","jboss.naming.context.java.module.bpm.bpm.env.jdbc.MAIL_SENDER_DBjboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.MAIL_SENDER_DBMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.module.bpm.bpm.env.jdbc.MAIL_SENDER_DBjboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.MAIL_SENDER_DB]","jboss.persistenceunit.\"bpm.war#org.jbpm.persistence.jpa\"jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.TASK_DBMissing[jboss.persistenceunit.\"bpm.war#org.jbpm.persistence.jpa\"jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.TASK_DB]"]}}}
```

JDBC_DB, MAIL_SENDER, TASK_DB and hubAdminDS are defined in the datasource

When I connect to the remote server there is no error but when I connect to the local server I have the above errors.

Anyone can explain, why I have thoses errors ? How I can correct it ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your datasource ("java:jboss/datasources/JDBC_DB") is not properly deployed inside JBoss  server, Follow the below steps to get this done:

**Install a JDBC driver as a core module:**

> 1.Create a directory under $JBOSS_HOME/modules. In this example: "$JBOSS_HOME/modules/com/oracle/jdbc/main".
>
> 2.Put the the JDBC driver jar (ojdbc6.jar) in this directory
>
> 3.Create a module configuration file module.xml:

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.oracle.jdbc">
  <resources>
    <resource-root path="ojdbc6.jar"/>
  </resources>
  <dependencies>
    <module name="javax.api"/>
    <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
  </dependencies>
</module>
```

Note that the jdbc driver jar must contain a META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver text file that specifies the jdbc Driver, otherwise the Java service provider mechanism used to load the driver will not work. From the main/common vendors only Informix does not have this out of the box.

> 4.Configure a datasource setting in standalone.xml or domain.xml.

You can now edit your standalone(-*).xml or domain(-*).xml to configure a datasource that references this module:

```
<subsystem ...>
    <datasources>
      <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/OracleDS" pool-name="OracleDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
        <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@myhostname:1521:oracle</connection-url>
        <driver>oracle</driver>
        <pool>
          <min-pool-size>10</min-pool-size>
          <max-pool-size>20</max-pool-size>
          <prefill>true</prefill>
        </pool>
        <security>
          <user-name>myuser</user-name>
          <password>mypass</password>
        </security>
        <validation>
          <validate-on-match>true</validate-on-match>
          <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleValidConnectionChecker"></valid-connection-checker>
          <stale-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleStaleConnectionChecker"></stale-connection-checker>
          <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleExceptionSorter"></exception-sorter>
        </validation>
      </datasource>
      <drivers>
        <driver name="oracle" module="com.oracle.jdbc">
          <xa-datasource-class>oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
        </driver>
      </drivers>
    </datasources>
  </subsystem>
```

or for an xa-datasource:

```
<subsystem ...>
      <datasources>
          <xa-datasource jndi-name="java:/XAOracleDS" pool-name="XAOracleDS">
              <driver>oracle</driver>
              <xa-datasource-property name="URL">jdbc:oracle:thin:@myhostname:1521:oracle</xa-datasource-property>
              <security>
                  <user-name>admin</user-name>
                  <password>admin</password>
              </security>
              <xa-pool>
                   <is-same-rm-override>false</is-same-rm-override>
                   <no-tx-separate-pools />
              </xa-pool>
              <validation>
                   <validate-on-match>true</validate-on-match>  
                  <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleValidConnectionChecker"></valid-connection-checker>
                  <stale-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleStaleConnectionChecker"></stale-connection-checker>
                  <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleExceptionSorter"></exception-sorter>
              </validation>
          </xa-datasource>
          <drivers>
               <driver name="oracle" module="com.oracle">
                   <xa-datasource-class>oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
               </driver>
          </drivers>
      </datasources>
  </subsystem>
```

Once DB-Driver is set up as a module and  server log says below:

```
12:10:47,381 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/OracleDS]
....
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to allow multiple connection to my database which was limited by the following command :

```
sqlplus / as sysdba

ALTER SYSTEM SET PROCESSES= 300 SCOPE=SPFILE; 
SHUT IMMEDIATE;
STARTUP;
```